# How to check size and extension of an image before upload in Aurelia-Typescript?

Tags: typescript, image, input, aurelia

I am trying to check image size and extension before upload in Aurelia/Typescript.
For this purpose: I have two classes:
i.e.
logo-extension.ts

```
export class LogoExtension {
  private logoExtension: string;

  constructor(logoExtension) {
       if (!(/(.png|.jpg|.jpeg)$/.test(logoExtension))) {
      throw "logo is in invalid format";
    }
    this.logoExtension = logoExtension;
  }
```

and my logo-size.ts is:

```
 export class LogoSize {
  private logoSize: number;
  private maximumLogoSize: number = 25000000;

  constructor(logoSize) {

    if (logoSize === undefined) {
      logoSize = "";
    }
    if (logoSize > this.maximumLogoSize) {
      throw "logo size should be less than 25MB"
    } else {
      this.logoSize = logoSize;
    }
  }
}
```

but the problem is that, in the main class,

logo.ts

, I am unable to get the extension and size of the image I upload, that is accessed by files.bind of aurelia.
I have used the following:

```
 getExtension(filename) {
    var parts = filename.split('.');
    return parts[parts.length - 1]
  }

  getSize(logo) {
    let inputFile = document.getElementById("file");
    return inputFile[0].size;
  }
```

also

```
 var x = document.getElementById('input'); // get the file input element in your form
    var f = x.files.item(0);
```

the `files` in the second-line always give the error. 
I don`t wanna use any external package/dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the code of

```
  getSize(logo) {
    let inputFile = document.getElementById("file");
    return inputFile[0].size;
  }
```

it's giving you error because it doesn't know the property `.size` on your element queried by `document.getElementById('file')`. Did you mean: `document.getElementById('file').files`?

If so, you also need to cast it to `HTMLInputElement`:

```
let inputFile = (document.getElementById('file') as HTMLInputElement).files;
```

Comment: Thanks, @bigopon,
But aurelia facilitated me. I made an array  this.companyLogo = []; and in used aurelia binding, value.bind(companyLogo) 
which provided with this.companyLogo.length and size to me. And then I passed them into the files.